# Must a git server have git installed?

Tags: git, ssh, server

I am trying to use my other machine as a bare git repo central, but I cannot install git on it.

Can I still git clone-push-pull via ssh?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: well, yah, that's a certain duplicate.

Comment: how did you find that?
it didn't come up in the related, or am I googlazy to scroll?

Comment: I used my magic Google powers.

Comment: I guess I should cut down on bing searching...